# Programs that require su permission dont work unless ran as sudo

Tags: permissions, software-center, password

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04 with openbox as my DE. The programs that require the sudo password get weird errors when i try to run the action that needs it. For instance if i try to install a program via ubuntu software center I get no popup for my password it just tries to install and says `Authentication Error Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.71'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages`. If I try to install a restore a disk image via gnome disks I get another permission errors.

TL;DR: Any program that has a popup for your password to do an action, the popup doesnt pop up

Comment: Have you tried `gksudo command_name` or `gksu command_name`?

Comment: This kind of authentication is provided by polkit rather than sudo - it probably means you either don't have the relevant polkit agent (probably `mate-polkit` on Mate?) or it's not getting started in your chosen session (maybe because the autostart / desktop file only starts it in the default desktops - look for a `OnlyShowIn` line)

Comment: `mate-polkit` is at the latest version. Also im afraid i dont understand the latter part of your suggestion

Comment: Look in the "Startup applications" tool, and make sure that Policy Kit is there and is enabled.

Comment: Does your system have a `/etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1.desktop` file? if so, please add its contents to your question

Comment: here it is http://pastebin.com/5bEAb9d2